# What does the '=|' operator do?

Tags: c

I googled but it doesn't return the results related to expression. I am guessing it has something to do with bits. What exactly does `=|` do?

Comment: Indeed `=|` is difficult to google, so take as a hint to google for "C operators".

Comment: |= is bitwise inclusive OR and assignment operator, "a |= b" is equal to "a = a | b"; =| doesn't have any meaning

Comment: Where you find this operator?

Comment: It could be old (K&R C) syntax, where `a =op b` means the same thing that `a op= b` means now.  This is invalid syntax now because `a =- b` is different from `a = -b`.  If that is the case, then you are looking at a *really* old code (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#K.26R_C).  The technical ("google-friendly") term for such operators is "compound operator" or "augmented assignment operator".

Comment: Looks like the no expression operator.

Comment: It throws a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm

So

```
  |   inclusive bitwise OR
  =   assignment
  |=  bitwise inclusive OR and assignment 
  =|  syntax error
```

As for |=

```
  a |= b;
```

equals to

```
  a = a | b;
```